# ¿Por qué no se aparecen las naves enemigas en mi juego?

Tags: c++, poo, sfml

intentando desarrollar un juego de naves y disparos con la librería SFML tengo el problema de que no consigo que aparezcan las texturas de las naves enemigas. El problema apareció luego de agregar un vector de balas al juego, desde ahí el vector de naves enemigas no se dibujo mas en la ventana.

El código es el siguiente:

clase Aircraft.h:

```
class Aircraft {
 private:
  sf::Texture texture;
  sf::Sprite mPlayer;

  float playerSpeed;
  sf::Vector2f playerDirection;

 public:
  Aircraft();
  sf::Sprite Render();
  void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
  sf::Vector2f getDirection() { return playerDirection; }

  void Up();
  void Down();
  void Left();
  void Right();
}
```

La clase Aircraft.cpp:

```
Aircraft::Aircraft() {
  texture.loadFromFile(
      "SFML-Game-Development-Book-master/02_Resources/Media/Textures/"
      "Eagle.png");
  mPlayer.setTexture(texture);
  mPlayer.setPosition(200.0f, 200.0f);

  playerDirection.x = 0.0f;
  playerDirection.y = 0.0f;
  playerSpeed = 220.0f;
}

sf::Sprite Aircraft::Render() { return mPlayer; }

void Aircraft::update(sf::Time dt) {
  mPlayer.move(playerDirection * playerSpeed * dt.asSeconds());

  playerDirection.x = 0.0f;
  playerDirection.y = 0.0f;
}

void Aircraft::Up() { playerDirection.y = -1; }

void Aircraft::Down() { playerDirection.y = 1; }

void Aircraft::Left() { playerDirection.x = -1; }

void Aircraft::Right() { playerDirection.x = 1; }
```

Clase Bullet.h junto con BulletFactory para las balas:

```
class Bullet {
 private:
  sf::Sprite sprite;

  sf::Vector2f speed;

  int posX, posY;

  Bullet(int _posX, int _posY, sf::Texture &_texture);

 public:
  friend class BulletFactory;

  void update(sf::Time deltaTime, int _posX, int _posY);
  sf::Sprite render();
};

class BulletFactory {
 private:
  sf::Texture texture;

 public:
  BulletFactory() {
    texture.loadFromFile(
        "SFML-Game-Development-Book-master/10_Network/Media/Textures/"
        "misil2.png");
  }

  Bullet create(int _posX, int _posY) { return {_posX, _posY, texture}; }
};
```

Bullet.cpp:

```
Bullet::Bullet(int _posX, int _posY) {
  sprite.setTexture(texture);
  sprite.rotate(-90);
  sprite.setScale(0.5f, 0.5f);

  posX = _posX;
  posY = _posY;

  sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);

  speed.y = -500.0f;
}

void Bullet::update(sf::Time deltaTime) {
  sprite.move(0, speed * deltaTime.asSeconds());
}

sf::Sprite Bullet::render() { return sprite; }
```

clase Enemy.h junto EnemyFactory para los enemigos:

```
class Enemy {
 private:
  sf::Sprite sprite;

  float speed = 190.0f;

  Enemy(int _maxX, int _maxY, sf::Texture &_texture);

 public:
  friend class EnemyFactory;

  sf::Sprite render();
  void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
};

class EnemyFactory {
 private:
  sf::Texture texture;

 public:
  EnemyFactory() {
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("SFML-Game-Development-Book-master/03_World/"
                              "Media/Textures/Raptor.png")) {
      std::cout << "no se pudo cargar la textura";
    }
  }

  Enemy create(int _maxX, int _maxY) { return {_maxX, _maxY, texture}; }
};
```

Enemy.cpp:

```
 Enemy::Enemy(int _maxX, int _maxY, sf::Texture &_texture) {
  sprite.setTexture(_texture);
  sprite.rotate(180);
  sprite.setScale(0.8f, 0.8f);

  sprite.setPosition(30 + rand() % 640, rand() % 400 - 500);
}

sf::Sprite Enemy::render() { return sprite; }

void Enemy::update(sf::Time deltaTime) {
  sprite.move(0.0f, speed * deltaTime.asSeconds());

  if (sprite.getPosition().y > 480) {
    sprite.setPosition(1 + rand() % 640, rand() % 400 - 500);
  }
}
```

La clase Game.h:

```
class Game {
 private:
  sf::RenderWindow *mWindow;

  ScrollingBackground background;

  Aircraft aircraft;

  std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
  EnemyFactory enemy;

  std::vector<Bullet> bullets;
  BulletFactory bullet;

 private:
  void proccesEvent();
  void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
  void render();

 public:
  Game();
  void run();
};
```

La clase Game.cpp:

```
Game::Game() {
  mWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "ventana SFML");

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    enemies.push_back(enemy.create(640, 480));
  }
}

void Game::proccesEvent() {
  sf::Event event;

  while (mWindow->pollEvent(event)) {
    if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
      mWindow->close();
    }
    if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed &&
        event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space) {
      bullets.push_back(bullet.create((aircraft.getPosition().x + 15),
                                      (aircraft.getPosition().y + 40)));
    }
  }
}

void Game::update(sf::Time deltaTime) {
  background.update(deltaTime);

  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)) {
    aircraft.Up();
  }
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)) {
    aircraft.Down();
  }
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) {
    aircraft.Left();
  }
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) {
    aircraft.Right();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
    bullets[i].update(deltaTime);
  }

  aircraft.update(deltaTime);

  for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
    enemies[i].update(deltaTime);
  }
}

void Game::render() {
  mWindow->clear();
  mWindow->draw(background.render());
  mWindow->draw(aircraft.Render());
  for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
    mWindow->draw(enemies[i].render());
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
    mWindow->draw(bullets[i].render());
  }
  mWindow->display();
}

void Game::run() {
  sf::Clock clock;
  while (mWindow->isOpen()) {
    sf::Time deltaTime = clock.restart();
    proccesEvent();
    update(deltaTime);
    render();
  }
}
```

Que puede ser lo que este causando el problema y como los soluciono?

Comment: Creo que ya se lo han comentado, pero si no tenga encuenta el formato del codigo que pone en sus preguntas, pues de no tener ningun tipo de formato hace mas dificil de leer su codigo, y mas aun cuando este es algo largo, pues el no tener un formato comodo de leer puede repercutir en el numero de usuarios que se interesen por su problema. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Según mis cálculos las naves enemigas se están pintando perfectamente en pantalla, pero en coordenadas negativas, esto se debe al algoritmo que usas para posicionarlas, en concreto esta instrucción:

```
sprite.setPosition(1+rand()%640,rand()%400-500);
```

El módulo (`%`) tiene una precedencia mayor que la suma (`+`) y la resta (`-`), así pues estás estableciendo los siguientes rangos para las posiciones de ese sprite:

- Eje horizontal (x): entre 1 y 640.
- Eje vertical (y): entre -500 y -101.

Como puedes ver, las naves enemigas están fuera de la pantalla. Puedes usar las herramientas de la cabecera `<random>` de C++11 para generar números dentro del rango que te interesa:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 generador(device());

void punto_aleatorio_en_pantalla(int &x, int &y)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> horizontal(0, 639);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> vertical(0, 479);

    x = horizontal(generador);
    y = vertical(generador);
}
```

Y usar la función `punto_aleatorio_en_pantalla` de la siguiente manera:

```
Enemy::Enemy(int _maxX, int _maxY, sf::Texture &_texture) {
    sprite.setTexture(_texture);
    sprite.rotate(180);
    sprite.setScale(0.8f, 0.8f);

    int x, y;
    punto_aleatorio_en_pantalla(x, y);
    sprite.setPosition(x, y);
}

void Enemy::update(sf::Time deltaTime){
    sprite.move(0.0f, speed * deltaTime.asSeconds());

    if (sprite.getPosition().y > 480){
        int x, y;
        punto_aleatorio_en_pantalla(x, y);
        sprite.setPosition(x, y);
    }
}
```

#### Editado

> [La idea de crearlos fuera de la pantalla con valores aleatorios en el eje `y` era que fueran apareciendo de a poco en la pantalla, ya que como se mueven en línea recta hacia abajo en algún momento deberían aparecer y luego al salir del rango de la pantalla se vuelven a re posicionar con valores negativos para volver a aparecer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65724/por-qu%c3%a9-no-se-aparecen-las-naves-enemigas-en-mi-juego/65854#comment120140_65854).

Bien, eso significa que las coordenadas negativas son algo deliberado. Pero eso no significa que sea correcto; en este caso deberías explorar otras opciones que te ayuden a comprender el problema como por ejemplo pintar las naves en posiciones visibles y observar si se mueven o simplemente depurar el programa mediante [puntos de interrupción [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint) o [mostrando cálculos intermedios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_(inform%C3%A1tica)) en la consola.

Por mi parte, he sacado mi bola de cristal y le he consultado tu problema<sup>1</sup>:
[image]

Me ha dicho<sup>2</sup> que tu problema está en la rutina de actualización del juego:

```
void Game::run() {
    sf::Clock clock;
    while (mWindow->isOpen()) {
        sf::Time deltaTime = clock.restart();
        proccesEvent();
        update(deltaTime);
        render();
    }
}
```

El bucle se está procesando tan rápido que la función [`sf::Clock::restart`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Clock.php#a123e2627f2943e5ecaa1db0c7df3231b) devuelve un tiempo tan pequeño que al multiplicarlo por la velocidad de la nave enemiga (`190.f`) siempre resulta en `0.f` o un valor tan pequeño que las naves no se mueven de manera perceptible, por ello no alcanzan nunca las coordenadas positivas y por eso nunca las ves.

Para confirmar si la teoría de mi bola de cristal es cierta: pinta las naves en coordenadas visibles y observa su comportamiento.

---

<sup>1</sup>No me ha quedado otro remedio que recurrir a la brujería, la información que aportas no es suficiente para adivinar tu problema sin usar la magia.

<sup>2</sup>En la foto se me ve con las uñas pintadas de rojo, ese día me apetecía pintarme las uñas.

Comment: Bien visto pienso que eso que comenta es el error que esta teniendo ahora mismo, pues segun me comento, con mi respuesta tampoco le aparecian, asi que creo que tenia dos errores. Saludos

Comment: la idea de crearlos fuera de la pantalla con valores aleatorios en el eje y era que fueran apareciendo de a poco en la pantalla, ya que como se mueven en linea recta hacia abajo en algún momento deberían aparecer y luego al salir del rango de la pantalla se vuelven a re posicionar con valores negativos para volver a aparecer. No creo que sea ese el problema ya que antes de implementar el arreglo de balas funcionaba perfectamente y no hice ningún cambio en el código mas que agregar las balas

Comment: @facundorotger *...No creo que sea ese el problema...* pues si no lo prueba usted que es el que tiene el codigo vamos bien, podria aclarar si con esos cambios la cosa sigue igual o no. Saludos

Comment: @facundorotger para esta respuesta aunque su logica funcione como espera donde usa esto `(1 + rand() % 640, rand() % 400 - 500)` o `(30 + rand()...)` pueden llegar a ser un problema pues si cambia el tamaño de la pantalla hara los calculos en base a los numeros magicos `640`y `400`, puede usar los  datos -> int _maxX, int _maxY, ajustarlos, guardarlos y usarlos en lugar de lo mencionado. Por otra parte si lo que se comenta en el update es uno de los problemas puede usar algo asi -> `clock.restart() +1` por ejemplo todo ira mas rapido despues asi que ajustar la speed base.Saludos

Comment: ...pero aun asi no se si eso afectara mucho, el uso de `clock.restart()` pues a mas rapido se ejecute, mas rapido el codigo y los update, con lo que igual el error no esta por ahi. Saludos

Comment: cambie la posición de inicio de la naves a un punto visible (200, 200) pero continua el problema. El programa compila bien, y no se detiene de forma inesperada ni me tira ningún error. Que otros datos le parecen necesarios y que yo no haya mencionado @PaperBirdMaster ? si  me parece importante resaltar que las naves enemigas se pintaban correctamente hasta que agregué el vector de **Bullets** al juego y ahi comenzo el problema

Comment: "*cambie la posición de inicio de la naves a un punto visible (200, 200) pero continua el problema*" ¿Te refieres a que continúan sin verse?

Comment: exacto. No aparecen las naves

Answer (score 2):

Segun este codigo:

```
void Game::render(){
    mWindow->clear();
    mWindow->draw(background.render());
    mWindow->draw(aircraft.Render());
    for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
        mWindow->(enemies[i].render());
    }
    for (int i=0; i<bullets.size(); i++){
        mWindow->draw(bullets[i].render());
    }
    mWindow->display();
}
```

Usted hace la llamada para pintar los objetos de esta manera:

```
mWindow->draw(bullets[i].render());
```

pero en la parte de los enemigos lo hace asi:

```
    for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
        mWindow->(enemies[i].render());
    }
```

puede ver la diferencia aqui -> `mWindow->(enemies[i].render());` intente cambiarlo por añadiendo `draw` quedando algo asi `mWindow->draw(enemies[i].render());` dentro del for.

Comment: @facundorotger *Ya le habia dejado una respuesta que creo que no ha visto, pero asi es mejor que creara una nueva pregunta pues la otra era sobre otro tema, que ya le explique en los comentarios.* Saludos

Comment: He corregido el error tanto en mi programa como en el código publicado aquí, sin embargo el problema persiste @Angel Angel

Answer (score 0):

mirando su codigo puede ver algo como lo siguiente:

clase bullet

```
Bullet(int _posX, int _posY, sf::Texture &_texture);
```

clase BulletFactory

```
Bullet create(int _posX, int _posY) { return {_posX, _posY, texture}; }
```

implementacion umm (si lo cambio en su fichero podria revisar antes de añadir el codigo)

```
Bullet::Bullet(int _posX, int _posY) {
```

---

aunque usted lo hace de diferentes formas para signar la textura en Bullet y en Enemy (usumiendo algunas cosas mencionadas antes), las puede revisar para ver que lo hace de forma distinta, en definitiva trate algo asi:

```
 Enemy::Enemy(int _maxX, int _maxY, sf::Texture _texture) {
  sprite.setTexture(_texture);
```

cambie -> `sf::Texture &_texture` por `sf::Texture _texture`

P.D: si esta teniendo error lanzados por su compilador, deberia de ponerlos en la pregunta.