# Por que no cambia el cuadro de una sprite sheet para crear una explosión?

Tags: c++, poo, sfml

tengo una sprite sheet de una explosión y estoy tratando de usarla en mi juego, el problema que tengo es que solo aparece en pantalla el primer "cuadro" y no cambia a los siguientes para crear el efector de "explotar". La sprite sheet en cuestión es de 1024X1024.

el código de la clase que maneja la explosión es el siguiente:

Explosions.h:

```
class Explosions {
private:
sf::Sprite sprite;

int rectx; 
int recty;

Explosions(float posX, float posY, sf::Texture &_texture);
public:
friend class ExplosionsFactory;

void update(sf::Time DeltaTime);
sf::Sprite render();
};

class ExplosionsFactory {
private:
sf::Texture texture;
public:
ExplosionsFactory(){
    texture.loadFromFile("SFML-Game-Development-Book-master/08_Graphics/Media/Textures/Explosion.png");
}

Explosions create(float posX, float posY){
    return { posX, posY, texture};
}
};
```

Explosions.cpp:

```
Explosions::Explosions(float posX, float posY, sf::Texture &_texture) {
rectx = 0;
recty = 0;

sprite.setTexture(_texture);
sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(rectx, recty, 250, 205));

sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);
sprite.setScale(0.6f, 0.6f);
}

void Explosions::update(sf::Time DeltaTime){
if (DeltaTime.asSeconds() > 0.5f){
    if (rectx >= 1024){
        rectx = 0;
        recty += 250;
    }else{
        rectx += 250;
    }

    if (recty >= 1024){
        rectx = 0;
        recty = 0;
    }
}

sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(rectx, recty, 250, 250));
DeltaTime.Zero;
}

sf::Sprite Explosions::render(){
return sprite;
}
```

Aqui se crean las explosiones, en la posicion de la nave enemiga que es destruida al entrar en contacto con una bala:

```
void Game::proccesCollisions(){

for (int i=0; i<bullets.size(); i++){
    for (int j=0; j<enemies.size(); j++){
        if (bullets[i].bounds().intersects(enemies[j].bounds())){
            explosions.push_back(explosion.create(enemies[j].getPosition().x-84, enemies[j].getPosition().y-68));
            enemies.erase(enemies.begin()+j);
            bullets.erase(bullets.begin()+i);
            enemies.push_back(enemy.create(640,480));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Aqui se llama a la funcion **update** de la clase explosions que en teoria deberia hacer cambiar el "cuadro" de la animacion de la explosion:

```
for (int i=0; i<explosions.size(); i++){
    explosions[i].update(deltaTime);
}
```

y del mismo modo recorro el vector para llamar a la funcion render().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problema.

No veo el código en el que alimentas a al método `Explosions::update` con un `sf::Time`; pero si lo estás haciendo como en el resto de tus preguntas ([esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63306/por-qu%c3%a9-no-se-muestran-los-sprites-en-la-ventana), [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64010/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-que-mi-nave-dispare), [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65724/por-qu%c3%a9-no-se-aparecen-las-naves-enemigas-en-mi-juego) y [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67487/cual-seria-la-mejor-forma-de-manejar-la-cadencia-de-disparo-de-las-naves-en-mi-j)) el código sería el siguiente:

```
void Game::run(){
    sf::Clock clock;
    while(mWindow->isOpen()){
        sf::Time deltaTime = clock.restart();
        proccesEvent();
        proccesCollisions();
        update(deltaTime);
        render();
    }
}
```

Por lo que, [tal y como dice Gerard097](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68466/2742), si el bucle de actualización es rápido estarás pasando un delta siempre menor a `.5f` y por ello la explosión se queda siempre en el primer fotograma.

#### Puntos de mejora.

Hay muchos puntos en tu código en que pueden añadirse mejoras, pero vamos a centrarnos en la clase `Explosions`:

1. No tiene sentido que el nombre de la clase sea en plural, ya que tan sólo gestiona una explosión.
2. Guardar las coordenadas del sprite es redundante, el propio `sf::Sprite` ya contiene estas coordenadas; tampoco necesitas almacenarlas si no cambiarlas según el tiempo.
3. Estás usando una textura de 1024×1024 con sprites de 250×250 (4,096 texturas por lado) pero tú compruebas los límites sobre 1024 no sobre 1000
4. El algoritmo que modifica la textura a mostrar está lleno de cadenas `if`-`else` cuando una división y un módulo sería suficiente.

#### Propuesta.

La clase `Explosions` puede controlar el tiempo de manera independiente usando la clase `sf::Clock`, el tiempo pasado desde el inicio del conteo del reloj, junto a la velocidad de refresco de la explosión (que parece ser `.5f`) nos indicará cuál es el fotograma a usar, así pues:

```
class Explosion {
    sf::Sprite sprite;

    // Un reloj por cada explosion.
    sf::Clock timer;

    Explosion(sf::Texture &_texture) {
        /* El reloj empieza a contar automaticamente
        en el momento de construirse */

        /* no establecemos el recuadro aqui, se hara
        en el proceso de actualización */
        sprite.setTexture(_texture);
    }
public:
    friend class ExplosionsFactory;

    void update() {
        // Averiguamos el fotograma en el que estamos.
        int fotograma = timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() / .05f;

        /* Calculamos la coordenada correspondiente a este fotograma
        asumiendo que son 16 fotogramas
        (250x250 en una imagen 1024x1024) son 4 fotogramas fila x columna */
        int sprite_x = fotograma % 4;
        int sprite_y = fotograma / 4;
        // Asignamos el recuadro del sprite.
        sprite.setTextureRect({sprite_x * 250, sprite_y * 250, 250, 250});
    }
    bool explosion_acabada() const {
        /* Averiguamos si la explosion se ha acabado, esto será
        si ha pasado mas tiempo que el requerido por todos los
        fotogramas de la animacion */
        return timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= (16 * .5f);
    }
    sf::Sprite render() { ... };
};

class ExplosionsFactory {
    sf::Texture texture;
public:
    ExplosionsFactory(){
        texture.loadFromFile("... blah blah ...");
    };

    Explosions create() {
        return { texture };
    }
};
```

Como puedes ver, calcular el fotograma es muy sencillo sabiendo cuando tiempo dura cada fotograma:

```
int fotograma = timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() / .05f;
```

Así, si (por ejemplo) ha pasado 2,0093 segundos sabemos que estaremos en el fotograma 4, ya que cada fotograma dura medio segundo:

> 2,0093 ÷ 0,5 = 4,0186

Al guardarlo en un entero (`int`) la parte decimal se trunca y obtenemos el fotograma 4. Esto es casi tan sencillo como calcular las coordenadas del fotograma sabiendo las dimensiones del mismo:

```
int sprite_x = fotograma % 4;
int sprite_y = fotograma / 4;
```

Si estuviéramos en el fotograma 10 de 16 obtendríamos los siguientes valores:

> 10 módulo 4 = 2
>
> 10 ÷ 4 = 2,5

Como estamos guardando los datos en enteros (`int`) sabemos que nos toca pintar el fotograma de la tercera columna y tercera fila (se indexa desde 0). Como ves no hemos hecho ningún `if`-`else` para averiguarlo, así que sabiendo que todos los fotogramas son de 250×250 nos permite establecer el recuadro del sprite así:

```
sprite.setTextureRect({sprite_x * 250, sprite_y * 250, 250, 250});
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- He añadido una función para comprobar si la explosión ha acabado, posiblemente lo necesites para eliminar las explosiones caducadas.
- Tu fábrica de explosiones ahora mismo crea un único tipo de explosión, si quieres (que querrás) más tipos de explosiones necesitaras indicar a la explosión los datos necesarios para pintarse:

  - Fotogramas de la explosión.
  - Tamaño de los fotogramas.
  - Inicio, final de los fotogramas en la textura.
  - Te aconsejo que todas las explosiones estén en la misma textura.
  - Velocidad de la animación de explosión.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el parametro que estas pasando a tu función update() de la clase Explosions, nunca esta siendo mayor a 0.5 segundos, ya que deltatime se resetea cada thick del juego por lo que es necesario que almacenes una variable en tu clase Explosions, que se encargue de contar el tiempo de vida de la explosión.

```
class Explosions
{
private:
    float m_fElapsedTime;
    const float m_kfFrameDuration;
    ...
};


Explosions::Explosions( float posX, float posY, sf::Texture &_texture ) : 
    m_kfFrameDuration(0.5f)
{
    m_fElapsedTime = 0.f;
    rectx = 0;
    recty = 0;

    sprite.setTexture( _texture );
    sprite.setTextureRect( sf::IntRect( rectx, recty, 250, 250 ) );

    sprite.setPosition( posX, posY );
    sprite.setScale( 0.6f, 0.6f );
}

void Explosions::update( sf::Time DeltaTime )
{

    m_fElapsedTime += DeltaTime.asSeconds();

    if ( m_fElapsedTime > 0.5f )
    {
        m_fElapsedTime = 0.f;

        if ( rectx >= 1024 )
        {
            rectx = 0;
            recty += 250;
        }
        else
        {
            rectx += 250;
        }

        if ( recty >= 1024 )
        {
            rectx = 0;
            recty = 0;
        }
    }

    sprite.setTextureRect( sf::IntRect( rectx, recty, 250, 250 ) );

}
```

Comment: Tienes un error en `sprite.setTextureRect( sf::IntRect( rectx, recty, 250, 205 ) );` el parámetro de altura es `250` no `205` (a mi me pasó igual xD).

Comment: Jaja es verdad ya quedo corregido, gracias por decirme no lo había notado.